# Parcelable for 2 classes android

Tags: android, inheritance, android-intent, parcelable

I'm still new in android so i'm a little bit confuse about parcelable. So here's my problem:
I have 3 class which are A,B,C. both **B and C are extended from A**.
I do already implement three of them the "Parcelable" and have all properties from A. B and C also have another properties beside from class A.

So in my MainActivity, i want to parcel them separately because in the first place i want to make the **A as the default** to use and load the data to another activity, but in another activity, i give the user some option whether they still want to use A's data or **want to change it to B or C's data**.

In the first place, i make that the user will not be able no go back to main activity (so there are more than 2 activity actually). and i plan to pass the B and C's data from the MainActivity so i dont need to call it all over again.

Here's my code :
Class A (parent)

```
public class A implements Parcelable{
private String name;
private int lvl;
private String job;

public A (String name, int lvl, String job)
{
    this.name = name;
    this.lvl = lvl;
    this.job = job;
}


//setter & getter
public void setName (String name) {this.name = name;}
public String getName () {return name;}

public void setLvl (int lvl) {this.lvl = lvl;}
public int getLvl () {return lvl;}

public void setJob (String job) {this.job = job;}
public String getJob () {return job;}

//Parcelable
protected A (Parcel source)
{
    this.name = source.readString ();
    this.lvl = source.readInt ();
    this.job = source.readString ();
}

public static final Parcelable.Creator<A> CREATOR = new Parcelable.Creator<A>()
{
    public A createFromParcel (Parcel source) {return new A(source);}
    public A[] newArray (int size) {return new A[size];}
};

@Override
public int describeContents () {return 0;}

@Override
public void writeToParcel (Parcel source, int flags)
{
    source.writeString (name);
    source.writeInt (lvl);
    source.writeString (job);
} }
```

Here is B and C code (actualy they have the same properties. only their job's name are different each other)

```
    public class B extends A implements Parcelable
{
    private int job_lvl;
    private int exp;

    //constructor
    B (String name, int lvl, String job, int job_lvl, int exp)
    {
        super (name, lvl, job);
        this.job_lvl = job_lvl;
        this.exp = exp;
    }

    public void setJob_lvl (int job_lvl) {this.job_level = job_lvl;}
    public int getJob_lvl () {return job_lvl;}

    public void setExp (int exp) {this.exp = exp;}
    public int getExp () {return exp;}

    //Parcelable
    protected B (Parcel source)
    {
        super (source);
        job_lvl = source.readInt();
        exp = source.readInt();
    }

    @Override
    public void writeToParcel (Parcel source, int flags)
    {
        source.writeInt (job_lvl);
        source.writeInt (exp);
    }

    @Override
    public int describeContents () {return 0;}

    public static final Parcelable.Creator<B> CREATOR = new Parcelable.Creator<B>()
    {
        @Override
        public B createFromParcel(Parcel source) {return new B(source);}

        @Override
        public B[] newArray(int size) {return new B[size[];}
    };
}
```

in the MainActivity :

```
    public class MainActicity extends Activity
{
    Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
    A a;
    B b;
    //C c;

    String name;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate (Bundle saveInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        //getText from user (input their name)
        //Name -> EditText

        name = Name.getText().toString();
        a = new A("", 1, "Novice");
        a.setName(name);
        //B (name, lvl, job, job_lvl, exp)
        bundle = new B(a.getName(), a.getLvl(), "Swordman", 1, 0);
        bundle.putParcelable ("Player", a);
        bundle.putParcelable ("Swordman", b);
        startActivity(new Intent(MainActivity.this,SecondActivity).putExtras(bundle));
        finish();
    }
}
```

in the SecondActivity:

```
    public class SecondActicity extends Activity
{
    Bundle bundle;
    A a;
    B b;
    //C c;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate (Bundle saveInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        bundle = getIntent().getExtras();
        a = bundle.getParcelable ("Player");

        //Displaying data from class A because it is a default

        //user make a choice in here whether they want to change their job or not

        //if they want to change then from class A change to class B's data
        if (//choose to become swordman)
        {
            b = bundle.getParcelable ("Swordman");
            //showing the data from class B
            //change all the activities which require A,B,C's data that depend on user's choice
        }

    }
}
```

and i got an error in this code :

```
a = bundle.getParcelable ("Player");
```

The Error says:

```
FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: danbin.game, PID: 15577
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{danbin.game/danbin.game.SecondActivity}: java.lang.RuntimeException: Parcel android.os.Parcel@25a544dc: Unmarshalling unknown type code 6357079 at offset 212
at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2379)
at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2442)
at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:156)
at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1351)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:211)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5373)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1020)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:815)
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Parcel android.os.Parcel@25a544dc: Unmarshalling unknown type code 6357079 at offset 212
at android.os.Parcel.readValue(Parcel.java:2259)
at android.os.Parcel.readArrayMapInternal(Parcel.java:2516)
at android.os.BaseBundle.unparcel(BaseBundle.java:221)
at android.os.Bundle.getParcelable(Bundle.java:755)
at android.content.Intent.getParcelableExtra(Intent.java:5089)
at danbin.game.PlayActivity.onCreate(SecondActivity.java:15)
at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5990)
at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1106)
at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2332)
at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2442) 
at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:156) 
at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1351) 
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:211) 
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5373) 
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372) 
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1020) 
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:815)
```

so can you guys help me to solved this? I already searched everywhere since 3 days ago but still can't find the solution.

I really appreciate all of your help!
Thank you

Comment: what is in getParcelable method in SecondActivity?

Comment: @OctavianoPutra ah i miss the bundle. actually it should be b.getParcelable("Player")

Comment: You cannot have two objects with the same variable name. `Bundle b` and `B b` in the activities.

Comment: @NarayanAcharya sorry for that. i already edit that. because it was just a example code so i didnt realize it.

Comment: Okay. Just make sure that you marshal and unmarshal your fields into the Parcel in the same order in both the classes A and B. Over here it looks correct, just make sure your local copy follows that too.

Comment: Are you forgetting calling super.writeToParcel (source, flags) in the  writeToParcel method in class B and C?

Comment: @NarayanAcharya okay thanks! i did already triple checked the Parcel are already in the same order in all of that class. so i'm still confuse right now.

Comment: @OctavianoPutra no i'm not forgetting about that. i already called super(source) in the writeToParcel method as you can see in above code. actually it works fine when i dont putParcelable for b (from class B) and dont call 'getParcelable' in the SecondActivity for b also.